# QGIS has an automatic way of finding the LS factor?

Tags: qgis, slope

I wonder if is possible to calculate LS (soil erosion) factor automatically in QGIS?
Or at least a way to calculate the length slope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both GRASS and SAGA have a number of functions which involve analysing soil erosion, sediment transportation and desposition. Just to give some examples in the hope that they might be useful in some way or another:

- **r.sim.sediment** from GRASS which simulates sediment transport/erosion/desposition
- **r.watershed** from GRASS which can calculate flow accumulation, watershed basins and slope length and steepness (LS factor)
- **slope length** from SAGA which calculates the slope length

You can access these from the *Processing Toolbox*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and time. It´s very useful for my studies.

Comment: Most welcome @VitorPinaSilva, hope you obtain the results you need!

Comment: Why is slope length SAGA is so different than r.watershed LS factor.